# SVG or PNG image from web as maker symbol (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, markers, web, data-defined-override

Is it possible to use a image (SVG oder PNG) from web (http) to use it as maker icon in QGIS?

In my case: Hiking Trails in OSM sometimes have a symbol as way marking (wiki:symbol). Here is one: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LDB-blau-OSM.svg
I would like to mark my OSM hiking trail (imported from OSM using ogr2ogr) with that symbol. Just typing in the URL is not working:

[image]

Finally I would like to use the data defined override, to get the right symbol for the trail, using `concat('https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:', "wiki_symbol" )`

Comment: I do not have an answer. So I can only suggest that you download the picture as a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works but you have to make sure to use the correct URL.

You have a link that points to a website (html file) containinge a link to the SVG:
[`https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LDB-blau-OSM.svg`](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LDB-blau-OSM.svg),

So you should use the correct path to the SVG file itself:

[`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/LDB-blau-OSM.svg`](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/LDB-blau-OSM.svg)

So be sure to concat the correct path to the symbol: `concat('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/', "wiki_symbol")` and the attribute `wiki_symbol` must contain the string `LDB-blau-OSM.svg`, see:

[image]